# skipping Function argument as SQL object

Tags: php, sql

There are instances that I need to write a function to do some jobs, and doing this job needs a connection to database. For the function to work, I pass a SQL object to it when calling it. Here is an example to better illustrate it:

```
function get_all_students($db)
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students");
  $stmt->execute();
  // and the rest of the code 
}
```

PROBLEM:

I want to declare the function without the need to pass `$DB` as the argument. I really like not to use sessions for this purposes.

because in all of my pages, at the very top, is this code included:

```
$db = new mysqli(SETTING);
```

and then function should already know $db, because it is been defined, but it does not untill it is been passed `$db` as its argument.

Comment: That's the way variable scope works (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). If you are using OOP I would recommend dependency injection but for single funtions, passing it as a parameter is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $db is out of scope within the function if not a session or a global.

Here's why:  If things operated the way you want them to, when you referenced objects not coded by you, if they used a variable you did and then altered that variables value, you would get unexpected behavior.  Each code block must be independant of the others or you will encounter very odd behavior as you call out to system functions which may use variables the same as yours.

Your choices are to either create and destroy the database connection object within the function or pass it in as you illustrated.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it but the best way imo is putting Singleton pattern or Registry Pattern.

[Check this link](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/design-patterns---singleton-and-singleton-registry)

You can get DB object from registry like:

```
Registry::get('db');
```

or via singleton

```
Db::GetInstance();
```

there is also "global" way but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I don't see that much difference between a `global` and a singleton.

Comment: I see difference. When you access object via singleton you have more control. I don't say that singleton is good but it is one of the solutions and there can be many.